# How to query/debug NSIS errors?

Tags: nsis

In my `Installer.nsi`. I have this in my uninstaller section:

```
ClearErrors

RMDir /r "$InstDir"

IfErrors 0 +2
  MessageBox MB_OK "Unable to uninstall all files."
```

During uninstall, I see the messagebox which indicates there was an error.

**Question**: How can I debug the error which causes the messagebox to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSIS cannot tell you which file it failed to delete nor why when you use a wildcard or `/r`.

If you don't have a lot of files/directories you can use a normal `Delete`/`RmDir` instruction for each.

The only way to get the error code from the filesystem is to use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and look at the failed operations.